# Send Custom Header Between Two Application ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, security, http

I have two different apps, A and B. App A has an `iframe` referencing App B.

So, my problem is that I have to pass a token from App A to App B, and I was wondering if is possible to create a custom header on App A and capture it on App B.

So far I can capture the basic headers like Cookie, Origin, etc on App B. but when I set up a custom header in App A it doesn't appear in App B headers.

App A headers, VB

```
Request.Headers("X-My-Custom-Header") = "testing"
```

**UPDATED**:
App B, C#

```
var origin = Request.Headers[@"X-My-Custom-Header"];
```

`origin` is `null` because it doesn't exists in the headers.

Comment: What does you code look like on App A to pass the information to App B?

Answer (score 1):

An `iframe` cannot specify additional headers to send in the request to app B. You are stuck with either setting cookies or adding something to the URL (the query string, for example). Arbitrary headers from the original request to app A are not going to be passed along to app B.

Comment: Have to be some way, I tried to do something with HttpWebRequest but is very difficult because you have to capture the responde from GetResponse Method and parse it to and string with a Stream reader and then Raw the html on the page, So, I will have to look for another strategy, I don´t know, a strategy like build a custom page on the App B and do all validations needed on it, and then redirect to the final page on App A with the response though

Answer (score -1):

Havent done this before, but you are writing in the header and reading from the cookies. Maybe write and read to the same?

Comment: yeah yeah my mistake, I have updated the question, I'm reading from the Request's headers on App B